# Flask - Why are some endpoints not HTTPS?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, https, gunicorn

I am building a web app using Flask. Currently I am using Gunicorn to serve the application and nginx to act as a reverse-proxy. Chrome Dev tools is complaining that one endpoint are not HTTPS:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com:88/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/geo2?coordinates='. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

In app.py I've setup HTTPS for Flask:

```
context = ('ssl/server.crt', 'ssl/server.key')
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, ssl_context=context, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

I am executing gunicorn with:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8282 app:app
```

My nginx config (leaving out all the SSL settings for brevity):

```
server {
    listen 88 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/app/;
    index index.html;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.5:8282/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
           }
}
```

I noticed I am only seeing this error for one endpoint, /geo2. My app is set to redirect to this endpoint when it receives a POST request at /geo. The code for that is:

`return redirect(url_for('reload_index', coordinates=coordinates))`

The POST request is being sent by Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/geo",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(coordinates),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I'm confused as to why any endpoints are HTTP given that Flask is set to use HTTPS. What am I missing? I taught myself all of this within the last few months, so it's very possible I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 5):

Read [Flask's documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups) that discusses this issue with proxies.

Flask isn't aware of what protocol your proxy server is using. You either have to tell Flask by setting the appropriate header in your nginx config file:

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

And then fixing your requests with a middleware:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

Comment: I previously stated that setting the PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME in Flask solved the issue, but in fact it has not. I've added the middleware code to my app.py, but the Chrome dev console is still blocking the HTTP request. 

I have an issue with my HTTPS cert that needs to be resolved before continuing to troubleshooting this. I'm also getting a "405 not allowed" error, and "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check" error. I suspect this is due to my current cert failing to match my domain. Adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header does not resolve it.

Comment: @AndyForceno: Sorry, I was mistaken. I've only used the middleware and assumed `PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME` would do what the docs implied it would. It doesn't have Flask choose HTTPS if the request was sent over HTTP, only if you create a request object yourself. HTTP 405 is "method not allowed", which doesn't seem related. I'd fix the certificate issue.

Comment: it's `from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix` in 2023